# How to simulate PC's Esc key on android

Tags: android, keyboard, key, simulate

I'm writing an app that can play flash on android, but I can't simulate ESC key, since a lot of flash games need ESC key to return to the main menu, without this key the app I made will be useless. So who could tell me how to simulate this? Can I just send a keycode? but I don't know the keycode too...

Answer (score 0):

Most games use the BACK key for this.... See http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0.html

Note that, while there is a key event ESCAPE (as Ezeh points out), that is only available at API level 11 (which is Android 3.0 and above - http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html), which is not very widely available in devices yet.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a look at the [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) property. There is a constant value for `KEYCODE_ESCAPE`.

You can learn more about how to implement it [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html)