# Recognising Escape Key

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I'm currently working on a practice program that works with various keyboard inputs so I can understand how they work in Android apps with Java. But I am struggling to get the `ESC` key to be recognised. The code below doesn't work. Has anyone ever managed to get the `ESC` key to work in an app? Is it actually possible?

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ESCAPE) {
                textView.setText("Escapekey pressed");
            handled = true;
        } 
        return handled;
    }
});
```

To summarize, I want the program to recognise the `ESC` key.

Comment: the question has already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530697/how-to-simulate-pcs-esc-key-on-android

Comment: Not receving this event on `onKeyDown` as well .?

Comment: No @sunny ' enter' key works fine. But escape works differently

Comment: I think `ESC` will trigger keycode `BACK` not sure though. You can try something like this  `keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ESCAPE || keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK`.

Comment: It didn't work thanks for trying. There must be a way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Android Emulator will not forward this key to the application, just like e.g. the function keys. Receiving these key events on a real device from a real keyboard works fine for me.